# How to get all ip from domain name?

Tags: firewall, hosts

I use

```
getent hosts domainname.com
```

As a result, I get only 10 ip.
I know that this domain name has a lot more ip. 
How to display them all?

This is a VPN server. I'm just trying to create allowing rules for my firewall.

Comment: Which version of Ubuntu are you using?